# Player jumps higher on iPhone 6 than iPhone 5s

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, gravity

I created an impulse:

```
impulse = frame.size.height/18
```

and gravity:

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, -2.85)
```

and I use this code to apply the impulse to the player:

```
hond.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, impulse))
```

Now when I test it on the simulator, the player jumps higher on the iPhone 5s simulator and lower on the iPhone 6 or iPhone 6 plus simulator.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: I think your problem is how you calculate the impulse. iPhone 5s screen is smaller than iPhone6/6s screen, so frame.size.height/18 will be different in each case

Comment: Thank you but didn't help, see my answer to Dean

Comment: You can use the vijeesh code to detect each device and personalize the impulse value

Answer (score 2):

Your impulse is `impulse = frame.size.height/18` depends of the height of the screen. But iPhone 6 and 6 plus have a bigger height than iPhone with a 4 inches screen.

This is why your player jump higher.

Comment: In your case the player should jump higher with the iPhone 6 plus, but it jumps lower. I changed impulse to: impulse = 18. still the iPhone 5s jumps higher than 6 and 6 plus..

Comment: Maybe the rest of your scene is also dependent of screen sizes ? If decor element depend of the size of the screen, then a fixed impulse won't help to have the same jump for every device

Comment: Thats right, rest of scene is dependent of screen sizes. is there any easier way to define the impulse instead of tracing which device is being used?

Comment: You can define the impulse dependent to the size of an obstacle for example ? With the right coefficient, it should be reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated version of https://gist.github.com/1323251

https://github.com/froztbytes/UIDeviceHardware

This will help you to find the device on which the app is currently running. Code according to the device and you can fix your issue

Comment: I implemented it in my project, but when I build it gives this error; use of undeclared identifier "UIDevice", pointing to the .m file

Comment: See the source code, this is only for simulator, in a real case you are not going to need to detect i386 or x86_64. Just return different value for each.